# Subsection not aligned with header subsection when using clearpage before subsection

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

I have implemented a custom subsection like this:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Question \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

And I would like to clear the page before each subsection so I added this

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

The problem is that I also would like to show the subsection in the right header by doing this:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thesubsection}
```

Problem: Subsection in header is 1.2 when subsection on page is 1.1

I also tried

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection}
```

But that just threw me an error...

EDIT: This is the full code of an example that shows the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\clearpage}


\renewcommand\thesection{Section \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Question \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thesubsection}
\lhead{}


\begin{document}


\section{}

\subsection{}
Subsec 1
\subsection{}
Subsec 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Fragments of code aren't really useful. Please post the minimal document that shows the error!

Comment: Ok now I updated it with a minimum not working example

Comment: Using a redefinition of `\thesubsection` will screw up the ToC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest to use a proper `question/answer` package instead of using `\subsection` this way, but here's a way to do it anyway.

I've additionally increased the `number width` spacing in the toc, otherwise the `Question 1.2.` stuff would be overprinting the dots in a possible usage of the ToC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thesection{Section \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Question \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}


\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{30pt}% Increase the 'number width'

\pretocmd{\subsection}{\clearpage}{}{} % Prepend `\subsection` with `\clearpage from now on...
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\ifnum\value{subsection} > 0\thesubsection\fi}
\lhead{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{}

\subsection{}
Subsec 1
\subsection{}
Subsec 2

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thesection{Section \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Question \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}


\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{30pt}% Increase the 'number width'

\makeatletter
\let\orig@subsection\subsection

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection} > 0 %
  \clearpage%
  \fi%
  \orig@subsection%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\ifnum\value{subsection} > 0\thesubsection\fi}
\lhead{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{}

\subsection{}
Subsec 1
\subsection{}
Subsec 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok great! It works apart from one thing, I do not want the section to have a page break before the first subsection. Could that be fixed? And then I do not understand etoolbox or tocloft?

Comment: @vikeri: `tocloft` is helpful for the ToC appearance, but `etoolbox` isn't needed really. I can fix

Comment: @vikeri: See the update please (at the bottom!)

Comment: Great stuff, now it works perfectly!